# Modifying existing object in one JSP file in another

Tags: java, jsp

I want to add another user in registration JSP file to my HashMap which is created in my homepage, but it seems the another HashMap is being created when I'm trying to register user.

How to access the HashMap from homepage JSP file in another?

This is my base class:

```
package com.jakub.spring;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class registeredUsers {

         public HashMap<String, String> userSource;

            public registeredUsers() {
                userSource=new HashMap<String, String>();
            }

            public void register(String name, String password) {
                userSource.put(name, password);
            }

            public String userExists(String user) {

                String passwordFromSource = userSource.get(user);
                if(passwordFromSource != null) {
                    return passwordFromSource;
                }else
                    return "";
            }


}
```

This is my homepage:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="true" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#CCCFFF">

<form method="post" action="validate.jsp">
<p align="left">Podaj login:</p>
<input type="text" name="name" />
<p align="left">Podaj haslo:</p>
<input type="text" name="password" />
<input type="submit" value="Zaloguj" />
</form>

<a href="register.jsp">Rejestracja</a>

<jsp:useBean id="registeredUsers"
        class="com.jakub.spring.registeredUsers" scope="application"></jsp:useBean>


<%

    out.println("Dostepni uzytkownicy w systemie: \n");
    out.print(registeredUsers.userSource.keySet()); 


%>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my registration page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-2"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2">
<title>Konto utworzone</title>
</head>
<body>

    <jsp:useBean id="registeredUsers"
        class="com.jakub.spring.registeredUsers" scope="application"></jsp:useBean>


       <%   

       registeredUsers.register(request.getParameter("name"),request.getParameter("password"));  

       out.print("Konto zostało utworzone");
       out.print(registeredUsers.userSource.keySet()); 


       %> 
       <a href="/spring/">Powrót do strony glownej</a>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) instead of `HashMap` because it's in **Application scope** and that can be accessed simultaneously by multiple threads at a time and it results in [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).

Please have a look at [Thread Safe JSP-Servlet Q&A](http://www.java2s.com/Questions_And_Answers/JSP-Servlet/Thread/Thread-Safe.htm)

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work for me. Actually I tried again with HashMap and it works now. None changes in JSP files done. Don't know what happened :) Thanks for answer anyway